# Smart groups break when database is restored

Tags: smartgroups

When we clone our production instance to staging, we restore the database with updated host information prior to restoring the database.

Querying a smart group returns all contacts in database, not just those in the smart group. Running the **Rebuild Smart Group Cache** scheduled job does not do anything.

Here Eileen says [How do the Rebuild Smart Group Cache scheduled job and the Smart group cache timeout setting interact?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31303/how-do-the-rebuild-smart-group-cache-scheduled-job-and-the-smart-group-cache-tim)

> Note I DO recommend running the job that flushes expired groups by
>   scheduled job - just not the one that rebuild them all, even the ones
>   you don't really need

Where is that job?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any such job, nor do I recall such a thing.

But: the contacts that are in smart groups are cached in `civicrm_group_contact_cache` so you should be able to clear that using the CiviCRM "cleanup caches" option (under Administer -> System settings).

Answer (score 0):

We are encountering the same problem. Whenever cloning the system (Drupal 7.98, CiviCRM 5.65.1) from production to staging, all smart groups are non-functional. Instead, all contacts of a certain kind become members of all smart groups. We need to manually correct it each time, which is quite some hassle.
Emptying the cache does not fix that.
The Drupal protocol shows the following message:

> https://xxx/civicrm/group?reset=1&update_smart_groups=1​
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
> CRM_Contact_BAO_SavedSearch::getFormValues() (Zeile 65 von
> /xxx/httpdocs/staging/public/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/SavedSearch.php).​

Anybody has a hint how to fix that?