# Changing Smart Group Update Frequency

Tags: smartgroups

I'd like to have a large number of smart groups but don't want to bog down the site when employees are using it. Is there a way to set up a smart group so that it will only update itself at a particular time of day, say only out of business hours sort of thing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `Rebuild Smart Group` schedule job enabled at `civicrm/admin/job?reset=1`?

[image]

Click on Edit and change the frequency to "Daily". Though, for exact time, you might need to write custom line in the cron file.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, updating of smart groups can be triggered both by the cron job as described  jitendra but also by many actions in CiviCRM. A large contact base and/or complex smart groups may lead to performance and deadlock problems and you also need to consider flushing the group cache. I would recommend to read this [SE question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31303/how-do-the-rebuild-smart-group-cache-scheduled-job-and-the-smart-group-cache-tim) and this [blog post](https://civicrm.org/blog/eileen/478-group-contact-cache-deadlocks-improvement) to understand CiviCRM's smart group behaviour a bit better.

A good approach could be to:

1. Set smart_group_cache_refresh_mode=deterministic
2. Set the smart group cache time in CiviCRM to 24 hours
3. Configure the cron job to update the smart groups once per night

Make sure to test your settings if you want to rely on your groups.

Comment: So #3  is setting up 'job.group_cache_flush' cron job daily?

Comment: I meant the cron job to rebuild the Smart Group Cache. It could probably not hurt to set up the "flush cache job" (as long as it runs before the rebuild job) but it would probably not be necessary if "smart_group_cache_refresh_mode" is set to deterministic.